# Retrofit 2 not working on release version of app

Tags: android, gson, build.gradle, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2 on my project and everything is working fine in debug mode. There is a login button that when I click that it shows a progress dialog and does a REST API call with retrofit and after the call, the dialog will be dismissed but in the release version of the app it's not working when I click the login button just nothing happens even dialog is not been shown.
What could the problem be?
Here is something that I used in my project :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

```
release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

Comment: did you try minifyEnabled false

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro 
check this link and add these in your proguard file if you want to minify, if not then simply minifyEnable false will work.

Comment: thank you, minifyEnabled false has worked but do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

**Retrofit is not working on release version of app**

Replace your this line `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` with

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
```